# Best way to access data in related tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

I have two tables that are conceptually related but the original coder did not create any FK relationship between the tables.

Table1:

```
TABLE [Name](
ID [varchar](10) NOT NULL (this is the PK),
MAIL_ADDRESS_NUM [int] NOT NULL,
BILL_ADDRESS_NUM [int] NOT NULL,
Shipping_Address_Num [int] Not Null
)
```

Table2:

```
TABLE [Address](
ID [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS_NUM [int] NOT NULL (this is the PK),
PURPOSE [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
```

If I had the option I would put FKs on the MailingAddress to AddressNumber, BillingAddress to AddressNumber, and ShippingAddress to AddressNum. But that is not an option.

Currently in my LINQ I do something like:

```
from n in Names.Where(predicate)
join ba in db.Addresses on n.BillingAddressNumber equals ba.AddressNumber
join sa in db.Addresses on n.ShippingAddressNumber equals sa.AddressNumber
join ma in db.Addresses on n.MailingAddressNumber equals ma.AddressNumber
```

If I understand EF and linq correctly I should be able to make that association in/on the Edmx design surface and simplify my query. Correct?

If so what steps need to be taken to add the correct associations to the Edmx files? I have found some references but they seem to involve a fair amount of manipulating the underlying XML files. Is that necessary? Also these tables are strictly read-only. Using VS2012 and EF5.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If these tables are 'strictly read-only', can you create a new view that pre-joins the tables and then import that to your EDMX? It will make your life much easier (and performance much better)...